# can not connect to socket inside vmware vm

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, virtual-machine

I created a server socket in C. This is the most basic stuff like what you would fine in a simple TCP server example. Server code is below. I also created a client socket that runs on the host machine. Code also below. However, for some reason the client is not able to connect to the server. The IP address I used is the same as the one under the entry eth0 from the "ip addr" command.  The network adapter of the VM is a bridged connection.

The exact same code works when both client and server run on the same machine (the host).

Thank you!

Server code:

```
int sockfd;
int clientfd;
struct sockaddr_in self;
struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
int addrlen = sizeof (client_addr);


if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
    perror("Socket");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

printf("Socket descriptor is: %d\n", sockfd);

memset(&self, 0, sizeof (self));
self.sin_family = AF_INET;
self.sin_port = htons(MY_PORT);
self.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &self, sizeof (self)) != 0) {
    perror("socket--bind");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

if (listen(sockfd, 20) != 0) {
    perror("socket--listen");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

clientfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &client_addr, &addrlen);
printf("%s:%d connected\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
```

Client Code:

```
int sock;
struct sockaddr_in server;
//struct sockaddr_in client; 
struct hostent *hp;
//char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];

if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    die(6, "Opening stream socket");

printf("Client socket file descriptor is: %d\n", sock);

memset(&server, (char) 0, sizeof (server));
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
hp = gethostbyname(host_name);
if (!hp) {
    //sprintf(buf, "%s: unknown host\n", host_name);
    die(8,  "%s: unknown host\n", host_name);
}
memcpy(hp->h_addr, &server.sin_addr, hp->h_length);
server.sin_port = htons((u_short) SERVER_PORT);

/* Try to connect */
if ((connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof (server))) < 0)
    die(7, "%s", "Failed to connect stream socket\n");
```

Comment: Have you checked if you have connectivity otherwise from outside the virtual machine, ie. the network settings are fine, do you have adapter set and it does get IP assigned etc?

Comment: I tried ping and it worked. Loss rate is 0%

Comment: And if you start the server can you check if it's listening? `sudo netstat -npla | grep :PORT`. Also try to connect to it with telnet from the host: `telnet VMIP PORT` so you can tell if your server app is fine

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9999            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3456/tcp_server

Comment: Define 'not able to connect'. There are several possibilities. Which is it? What does perror() print? NB When you get an error from a system call, don't just print a message of your own devising. You're suppressing useful information that way.

Comment: perror does not print anything. None of the code on the server side fails or produces any errors. The only issue I am having is at the client side. It fails to connect. I see the error message from the last line which says: "Failed to connect stream socket"

Comment: Sigh. That's *your* message. It is of no interest or use whatsoever. It doesn't tell us anything more than connect() returned -1. What does perror() print *at the client?*

Comment: Oh...you mean the generic perror in libc! ok...that prints ": Connection refused". I know connection refused usually means that the server was found but it is not listening on that port. I check the ports on both client and server and they match. May be firewall?

Comment: Well I don't know what *other* perror() I would be talking about. Could be a firewall problem, although they more usually result in connection timeouts. What was the answer to the telnet question?

Comment: telnet 192.168.248.131 9999
Trying 192.168.248.131...
Connected to 192.168.248.131.
Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: I know that you can specify what subnet a socket is supposed to listen to (and accept messages from). I specified INADDR_ANY when creating the socket and binding.

Comment: Your server-side bind and listen are all OK. If telnet from the client host works the client should work from there too. I suspect you just aren't using the correct target IP or port in the client. Print them out before you connect.

Comment: I did verify the IP address and port I copied and paste the stuff and I am beyond positive that they are right. I think it is some sort of setting I added to the client socket. I will keep looking. this is stupid. Never ran into something stupid like this in my recent history.